# Let address link open hide section in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, display

I am new in JS so my question is it possible if I have many sections and I can open them when click on button (they are `display: none;` by default and opens when click on menu button on same page). I need to create links that if someone enters in address box then that sections opens... but how to make that if its `display: none;` by address? Maybe i am wrong and you can suggest some better method ?

```
<section style="display: none;" id="sectionIepirkumi" class="w3-container w3-threequarter section">
  <div id="sectionTopLine" class="w3-border-top w3-border-green"></div>
  <h5 id="sectionAddress" class="w3-margin-bottom">
    <a id="sectionAddressFirstPageLink" class="sectionAddressLink" onclick="openSection('sectionFirstPage')">
          Sākumlapa </a>/
    <a class="sectionAddressLink" onclick="openSection('sectionAboutSchoolPage')"> Par Skolu </a>/
    <a class="" style="font-weight: bold;"> IEPIRKUMI</a>
  </h5>
  <div id="sectionBottomLine" class="w3-border-top w3-border-green w3-margin-bottom"></div>
  <div class="w3-panel w3-border">
    <h3>Uz doto momentu nav aktuālu iepirkumu!</h3>
  </div>
</section>
```

```
function myFunction(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
    x.className += " w3-show";
  } else {
    x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call myFunction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making it complicated, because of it(instead of using **if..else**) there is a method for [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), which lets you toggle the class of the element you want. The method is [toggle()](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp).

Later you can create a class named `.show` which will change the display of your element to **block** when the class is given to the element.

**Reminder** : Don't ever use `var`, use `let & const` which are the newest syntax. ([ecma-script 6](http://es6-features.org/))

```js
function myFunction() {
  const container = document.getElementById('sectionIepirkumi');
  
  container.classList.toggle('show');
};

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

```css
.show {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<button type='button'>Click</button>

<section style="display: none;" id="sectionIepirkumi" class="w3-container w3-threequarter section">
  <div id="sectionTopLine" class="w3-border-top w3-border-green"></div>
  <h5 id="sectionAddress" class="w3-margin-bottom">
    <a id="sectionAddressFirstPageLink" class="sectionAddressLink" onclick="openSection('sectionFirstPage')">
          Sākumlapa </a>/
    <a class="sectionAddressLink" onclick="openSection('sectionAboutSchoolPage')"> Par Skolu </a>/
    <a class="" style="font-weight: bold;"> IEPIRKUMI</a>
  </h5>
  <div id="sectionBottomLine" class="w3-border-top w3-border-green w3-margin-bottom"></div>
  <div class="w3-panel w3-border">
    <h3>Uz doto momentu nav aktuālu iepirkumu!</h3>
  </div>
</section>
```